# Issues changing the value of an element in an array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm simply trying to create a program that will sum the `n-1` and `n-2` numbers to create `n` and store the value in an array. Currently, the output (assuming `numDisp > 2`) will be `num1`, `num2`, `0`, `0`, `0`... The size of the array is correct, I'm just having issues reassigning the elements.

```
num1 = input('Input your first integer of the fibonacci sequence: ');
num2 = input('Input your second integer of the fibonacci sequence: ');
numsDisp = input('How many integers would you like to display? --> ');

list = zeros(numsDisp,1);
list(1) = num1;
list(2) = num2;    

if (numsDisp <=0)
   disp('Value must be an integer greater than zero.')
elseif (numsDisp == 1)
   disp(num1)
elseif (numsDisp == 2)
   disp(num1)
   disp(num2)
else
   disp(num1)
   disp(num2)
   for index = 3:numsDisp
       disp(list(index))
       list(index) = list((index-1)) + list((index-2));
   end

end
```

example input: `3 3 4`

corresponding output: `3 3 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't printing out the final result, only intermediate steps. In your `for` loop, you are printing `list(index)` then updating its value, rather than updating its value then printing it.

Add `disp(list)` after the final `end` to print out the result.